# Django Haystack foreignkey relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, solr, django-haystack

i have model like this:

```
class Photo(ImageModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, unique=True)
    title_slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name", blank=True)


class GroupUpload(ImageModel):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Group Name", max_length=75)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Added", 
            default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    caption = models.TextField(verbose_name="Caption", blank=True)        
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='+', 
          verbose_name=_('F'),null=True, blank=True, through='GroupuploadPhotos')
```

my Search Index:

```
class PostIndex(indexes.RealTimeSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable): 
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)     
    date_added = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_added')

    def get_model(self):
        return Photo

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_added__lte=
                                                    datetime.datetime.now())
```

now i want to get object of GroupUpload which has relation with Photo. with this defination i am getting only Photo object not related object in GroupUpload.  i have checked doc. but havent solved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you drop the `related_name='+'` in your `class GroupUpload`, what's happened ?

**UPDATE:**

> Why not set related_name='group_uploads' and use
>   photo.group_uploads.all() (or if it as haystack SearchResult -
>   result.object.group_uploads.all())?

regards

Comment: you can get some info from here about related_name, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: @Aragon: Why don't you want to have a backwards relation?

Comment: @Bernhard Vallant entirely due to my not thinking of meeting like a problem.... do u have any solution for this issue? still i have been working on it.

actually if my models are in separate models.py, i can write new RealTimeSearchIndex for my groupupload too.. but not such thing.

Comment: Why not set `related_name='group_uploads'` and use `photo.group_uploads.all()` (or if it as haystack `SearchResult` - `result.object.group_uploads.all()`)?

Comment: thk u very much @Bernhard. i have solved it with your direction as related_name='group_uploads'